# How does Acrobat's 'export' feature interpret text without meaningful TTF glyph mappings?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, acrobat, truetype, cups

I have a PDF where copy/paste will produce garbage, and looking at the internals the text is defined with values outside a typical ASCII range. Character values are allocated sequentially based on the order they are seen 0x01, 0x02, and so on. This means that copy/paste and tools like `pdftotext` don't work. It says it was made with `ghostscript` but I think this was via `cups` which I'm less familiar with.

**My question then is why can Acrobat's 'export' feature reproduce completely readable text when exporting to plain text or HTML?**

I think I have a clue but don't know enough to follow it to the end.

I noticed the first word encountered in the PDF stream data starts 'Think' and these bytes are allocated as 0x01, 0x02, etc.

I cropped that font from the PDF data and ran `ttfdump` where the `cmap` table looks like this for Platform ID 1 (with similar values for ID 3):

```
Char   1 -> Index 55
Char   2 -> Index 75
Char   3 -> Index 76
Char   4 -> Index 81
```

If these are mapped to ASCII codes, they don't correspond directly but their distance from each other makes sense - 'T' is 20 less than 'h' which is 1 less than 'i' and so on.

So my first question would be, is it likely Acrobat is using this to derive values? And the followup would be to understand more about how these values are used if it's simple to explain. I have skimmed the  font format spec but it's quite long and I'm not sure what to focus on.

P.S. I can supply the font if required but not the PDF which has private data (we do not produce nor own it). I also don't think writing a program to extract text automatically is sensible in this case, but I'm trying to gather information for the inevitable 'But Acrobat can do it!' complaints.

Comment: Well, apparently they have to make use of information in the font program as other sources have been used in regular text extraction. Which information exactly therein they use, well, I assume they use a combination of properties they can extract from it. In particular there may be an explicit mapping to Unicode in it, too.

Comment: I was hoping someone else had looked into it, or failing that, knows what metrics in a font would reveal this information. It seems that most tools only go skin deep i.e. the characters inside the PDF content streams. I'm not sure what a next level approach would be and it would be great to know.

Comment: *"It seems that most tools only go skin deep"* - well, most text extractors simply implement the algorithm outlined in the pdf specification which also ignores what's in the font programs themselves.

Comment: Fonts used in PDF optionally have a "ToUnicode" CMap which map the character codes used with those fonts, to (not surprisingly) Unicode values. The main reason that Ghostscript won't embed a ToUnicode CMap into a PDF for a given font is that the input file doesn't include one (which, if the input was Postscript, it *definitely* won't). As for what the values in a TTF cmap table mean, do a search for the OpenType spec, the tables are quite well documented there.